# The using of address ZTEXTADDR in Linux booting for ARM

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, bootloader

What is the role of **ZTEXTADDR** in Linux kernel ?

From [lxr.linux.no](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.12.1/Documentation/arm/Porting#L16), it's an address in RAM that holds address of zImage as sequence below?

**A.**

```
uImage (DataFlash/NAND) ---load_to_RAM---> 
 uImage (@ boot_addr) ---decompress_uImage--> 
  zImage (@ ZTEXTADDR) --- decompress_zImage---> 
   uncompressed image (@ ZRELADDR).
```

or just:

**B.**

```
uImage (DataFlash/NAND) ---load_to_RAM---> 
 uImage (@ boot_addr) ---decompress_uImage--> 
  uncompressed image (@ ZRELADDR)
```

no using ZTEXTADDR in new kernel version for booting process ?

Answer (score 2):

The Linux ARM decompression boot loader is capable of relocating itself when running from RAM.  The relocation portion is PC-relative and so it can be loaded at any address.  However, if your main image starts from FLASH/ROM, the code can not be relocated; while moving an image in RAM is a simple `memmove()`, it is much more involved for NOR flash and can be impossible for ROM.

In [this case](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/compressed/Makefile?id=refs/tags/v3.13-rc2#n72), a [compressed boot linker script](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux.lds.in) is used with the **ZTEXTADDR** as the location of the decompression code.  In your diagram, you have a *u-boot*, which will load the *uImage*.  There is no reason to execute this directly from Flash/ROM.  *u-boot* can copy the image to RAM and there is no need for the **ZTEXTADDR** value and it should be left as zero.

If your image boots directly from Flash/ROM, without a boot loader then **ZTEXTADDR** is useful,

```
 zImage (in flash) --> decompress vmlinux.bin to RAM --> run kernel
```

The *zImage* may need to be annotated with some chip setup for this to work and would need **ATAGS** or device trees linked.  For this reason, there are many machine variants in [*boot/compressed*](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/compressed); This is not maintainable and these type of files are discouraged.  Typically another bootloader loads the image to RAM and the *zImage* can move itself to whatever destination it needs; I think that is your situation and you should set **ZTEXTADDR** to zero and forget about it.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. So, in case of ZTEXTADDR is used, then do we need the address **ZRELADDR** ?.

Comment: Generally *zreladdr* is automatic now.  See [head.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S?id=refs/tags/v3.13-rc2#n171).  The *auto* code gets the PC and masks the high *seven* bits.  **ZRELADDR** is used as the final physical address of the kernel image (decompressed to RAM).  However, this is already setup in the [vmlinux.lds.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S) and must match the `virt_to_phys()` macros.  So it is better not to use it if possible.

Comment: you mean: In case of booting directly from ROM/Flash, then ZTEXTADDR is physical address of decompressor code (of zImage) in ROM/Flash ? And  decompressor code will decompress zImage in ROM/Flash to  ZRELADDR in RAM where is address of decompressed image (vmlinux.bin) ? The macro that you mentioned is : `__virt_to_phys(TEXTADDR) == ZRELADDR` ?

Comment: In the case of direct ROM/Flash decompress to RAM.  `ZTEXTADDR` is the physical address of the ROM and `ZRELADDR` is the physical address of the RAM; we also need a ZBOOT_ROM_BSS for decompressor RAM.  There is no MMU or `virt_to_phys()`; for the RAM to RAM case, the code will move to where ever it like as long as it is within the RAM region; the MMU can just remap things.  In the RAM to RAM case, the code can inspect where it is running from (physical) and work out where to move for virtual.